# CoreData or Not with Restkit

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, restkit

The question is to use or not CoreData with Reskit, it's because i don't know what are the benefits of using this or in what case is recommended to use it.

This questions is because i have an application with CoreData (the old developer did this work) and i feel that it consume a lot of resources and make the application slow.

I have a newsfeed so the data in here is always changing so i don't need to persist the data i think? BUT i have some objects like my profile picture and preferences that i want to store locally.

****UPDATE****

It's the code to define the "persistence" (i think)

```
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    RKObjectManager* man = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL]];
    man.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
    [RKObjectManager setSharedManager:man];

    [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;

    RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
    man.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

    //configuring Mappings
    /**some mappings**/

    [managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
    NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sqlite"];
    NSError *error;
    NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
    NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

    // Create the managed object contexts
    [managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

    // Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
    managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache;
```

Comment: What are your performance issues, and why is it you believe that Core Data is causing them? It's actually quite fast and well-optimized, and in most cases will give you better results than using a SQLite store directly (and is easier to work with). What are your storage needs exactly, and what else are you considering? If you don' need to persist data at all, then by all means don't! Otherwise, the question should really be "what alternatives to Core Data are more appropriate to this problem?"

Comment: @ReidBelton sometimes it takes much time mapping i think? or saving things in the local db, but i'm just trying to understand it. Maybe i have misunderstanding somethings, i think it's CoreData? but i know it's using SQLite (See update). In the meanwhile i only need to storage some user preferences and some data (like avatar, bio, and application config)...i think the question is "wrong" but i cannot articulate another one for the moment

Comment: Core Data is very efficient and very easy to use. There are very few reasons not to use Core Data in my opinion…about the only time I've gone with SQLite in iOS recently is when I needed full-text-search. If you're having performance issues with Core Data, the problem is with your design and SQLite is not going to fix that. If you're not having a problem…well, you're not having a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Core Data. Also look at using fetched results controllers (to manage the batch loading of pages of data from your data store). This would be perfect for a newsfeed app where you will likely have a relatively large number of feed items but not many of them will be on display at any one time (so you don't need them in memory). To manage this yourself using raw SQLite or data in a file on disk will be more work and probably less performant.

Comment: but the data is only for "cache" or it's permament?

Comment: ? Core Data can do either depending on how you configure it. When using RestKit it will create a persistent (permanent) store.